# creating a table that has single row and multiple colums

Tags: html

- DATE  12/8/2017
- INVOICE # [123456]
- CUSTOMER ID   [123]
- DUE DATE  1/7/2018

How to create a table for this?
The data should be in the table and attributes should be parallel to them outside of table.

Comment: Please create a representation of the desired output. Also try to solve what seems a contradiction between title and body of the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: doc here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics